# eval json out of memory error

Tags: javascript, json, eval

I'm using `JSON.parse` function to load info about a cellset. I'm testing how much data is possible to fetch in one call.

The eval function starts throwing "out of memory" between 1.3-1.4 million characters (65,000-70,000 cells) in the JSON string. Does anybody know of a workaround for this - perhaps a pure JSON parser, rather than eval?

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the ajax-concept here by fetching 1.4 million chars at once

Comment: Why are you loading such large data? Try to implement paging or lazy loading perhaps.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have a similar problem. In my problem I am loading vector graphics using ajax and the number of entities (and the size of the response) can vary wildly. I am considering the possibility that eval may cause OOM exceptions if the image has too many entities.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend this one: http://json.org/js.html it's efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely pushing way too much information to your client.

Possible workarounds:

- Page your data and only load what is visible
- Avoid JSON, use HTML and dump the HTML directly to the page with .innerHTML
- Maybe use a native JSON parser like in Firefox and IE8 (possibly in other browsers, can't remember)
- Try JSONP (including a script tag that calls a function with your data as an argument)